# What's wrong with level shifter output?

Tags: debugging, hdmi, level-translation

I was trying to understand what wrong about the output of the level shifter, the level shifter is part of my circuit that I trying to bring-up and encountered difficulty in this issue.
This is the circuit:

[image]

OE controlled by FPGA, the 5V and 3V voltages works well in other components in the circuit.

I measured the VCCA&VCCB their inputs are 5 and 3.3V respectively, the input from Retimer is 3.3V and the output of the level shifter is **2.5V**, That's wrong because I need 5 volts for HDMI  interface- As you can see these signals go to an HDMI connector and routing with cable to Test Pattern Generator Board(TPB).

The signals measured as stated at 2.5 volts are measured both before and after the FB (FL4,FL3).

[image]

I want to note even if the TPB is disconnected the voltage still 2.5V without any HDMI cable connected.

EDIT: attaching more relevant information for HDMI signals and pull-ups.

P1 connector is female connector that carrier DRACO TX MODULE(shelf product), I just design the carrier for it:

[image]
signals from manual requesting(DRACO SIDE):
[image]
If anyone can help me about this issues it would be much appreciated!

Comment: If that's your whole schematic, it has no way of working. You might even destroy something as HPD is not bidirectional and CEC is not even a 5V signal, and most likely the rise time acceleration just causes problems. That is definitely not HDMI compliant and just by the looks of it, not even compatible. You won't be able to sell that without changes.

Comment: @Justme Are you series? I focus on the question where there is a problem, obviously it is not the whole circuit, I took here the level shifting of specific  signals, of course there are more signals and components in the circuit there are of course more information and clock signals that belong to HDMI but they are not relevant to my question

Comment: I don't mean TMDS signals, I only mean the signals you presented, and saw the problems. Well, if that is not your whole circuit, then show it. For now I can just say you have missing pull-ups, but next thing you say is you have them, then I have to ask what value they are, so it would be easier if you just showed the circuit. But looking at the chip specs what it requires to work, will not be within what HDMI specs require to work. You need to compare the specs to see that is just an unsuitable level shifter for the job.

Comment: @Justme Accepting your claim you are right, I have added the relevant things on the part of the connector, please read the edit note the PCB most of the contents of the my board is to serve as a carrier board for a module that is a shelf product(DRACO TX)

Comment: That is the 3.3V FPGA side? What about the 5V HDMI side? If I try googling for "draco tx module" I can't find anything so you could add a link to that module and the documents for it.

Comment: @Justme It's a confidential product, they provided us with a schematic of the carrier board they made and I relied on it, they also gave instructions for carrier and I attached what they wrote about these specific signals, the TPB is a separate board that produces only the video and not related to my card(just with connection the HDMI cable ), I can attach the schematic of TPB of specific signals

Comment: maybe is will help to understand all the "system" https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/623698/hdmi-debug-issues-over-wireless?noredirect=1#comment1647748_623698

Comment: Oh that question. Yes well the level shifter being "too smart" may cause I2C communication issues. And I2C is needed for higher resolutions. And HDCP. The level shifters may be unsuitable for I2C,  CEC and even for HPD.

Comment: @Justme In the TPB there is the same logics of level shifting just in the opposite side (from 5v -> 1.8v to the FPGA I/O) , the TPB works well for years with hundreds of different monitors

Comment: *It's a confidential product* Then ask them for support! And I'm sorry to say that *everything* is wrong with this circuit. You can erase it and do it again, with the HDMI spec in hand. You cannot guess at this stuff. Yes, the spec isn't free, but it's the cost of doing business.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica what wrong on this circuit? apart from the voltage translation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TXB0102 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/document-viewer/TXB0102/datasheet) says:

> The TXB0102 is designed to drive capacitive loads of up to 70 pF.

So it does not work with long traces, cables, or connectors.

> If pullup or pulldown resistors are connected externally to the data I/Os, their values must be kept higher than 50 kΩ to assure that they do not contend with the output drivers of the TXB0102.

So you cannot use it for the CEC signal.

> For proper operation, the device driving the data I/Os of the TXB0102 must have drive strength of at least ±2 mA.

So you cannot use it for the HPD signal.

The HPD signal is slow and unidirectional, so you can use pretty much any level shifter (except the TXB). But for the CEC signal, you need a shifter that can handle open-drain signals, like the TXS0102.

Comment: Please look at my schematic, TXS is connected to I2C signals.
I need to check if TPB did any use in CEC signals. what are you think about it? 
this signal is must?

Comment: I am not talking about the I²C signals.

Comment: Got it. BUT if the TPB does not use any CEC signals(its connected to his FPGA but there is no use it) what is the meaning of this?
and if you said about the HPD is a slow and unidirectional ,why is output 2.5v? the cable is connected the DRACO output is 3.3v and the output of HPD is 2.5v

Comment: The load is too high for the TXB. You cannot use the TXB.

Comment: 1. Please can you tell me how you calculate it ? I mean how you calculate that CEC sink more than 2mA?
2.I will say again, the TPB does not depend on anything he always shoots video no matter what control signal he receives, even the HPD and CEC do not include into the logic of the FPGA (the FPGA in his board produces the video)

Comment: 1. If you have to ask, then the load is too high. The TXB works only with short traces on the same board. 2. This question is about the level shifter output.

Comment: Thanks, but I mention, the HDMI cable disconnected and still got the same 2.5v, what can make over load in the output if there is nothing connected?

Comment: Some load you have not shown, probably a pull-up/-down resistor.

Comment: please look at the schematic that I added.
The input include pull-up resistor with 10kohm from the 3.3v side, and the output is routing to connector with FB so if the cable disconnected there is nothing in the output(only the Ferrite),and only input with CEC signal and 10kohm resistor. 
the 10kohm consider overload? even if its in the input?

Comment: The TXB is bidirectional; its output drivers on both sides are always active.

Comment: Thanks, if I will change the 10kohm resistor to 50kohm its will fix the problem?
please help me, I do not want my manager to scold me, I really designed this board in a calculated way

Comment: The pullup is only one of the many problems. You cannot use the TXB0102. Replace it with the TXS0102.

Comment: TXB is for push-pull signals. CEC and HPD are neither. CEC is open-drain. HPD has 1kohm output impedance, it could be open-drain as well. And having level convrsion to 5V on CEC is just plain wrong because it is not a 5V signal.

Comment: @CL I still have a question I'm not sure about, if the HPD is a signal of 3.3v(from DRACO module datasheet) and output impedance of 1kohm mean driver strength of 3.3mA, am I wrong? about the CEC the issue is understood.

Comment: A current of 3.3 mA through a 1 kΩ resistor would drop the voltage to 0 V. And you are indeed seeing a voltage drop.